Misplaced and inverted text added to PDF using itext
I have 300-400 PDFs in a directory. They need to be merged into one PDF, sorted by name, and page numbers should be added according to their total count in the merged file. I read the contents of the directory, sort the array of file names, and merge them one by one in the following way:
foreach (var file in projectFiles)
{
    PdfDocument projectPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(file));
    merger.Merge(projectPdf, 1, projectPdf.GetNumberOfPages());
    currentPage += projectPdf.GetNumberOfPages();
    projectPdf.Close();
}

The PDF file is merged, and it displays correctly in the reader. I call a function that is supposed to add the page numbers:
public static void AddPageNumbers(PdfDocument pdfDoc, int totalPages)
{
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);
        int currentPage = 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
        {
            var currentPagePara = new Paragraph((currentPage).ToString())
                .SetFontSize(10);
            var totalPagesPara = new Paragraph(totalPages.ToString())
                .SetFontSize(10);
            
            doc.ShowTextAligned(currentPagePara, 500, 20, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
            doc.ShowTextAligned(totalPagesPara, 530, 20, i, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.BOTTOM, 0);
            
            currentPage++;
        }
        doc.Close();
}

Unfortunately, when I run this, I get this:

Now, if I run almost the same code with the newly created PDF document using this code:
string dest = "output.pdf";

PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

Document document = new Document(pdf);

var para1 = new Paragraph("18");
var para2 = new Paragraph("1033");
        
document.ShowTextAligned(para1, 500, 20, 1, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
document.ShowTextAligned(para2, 530, 20, 1, TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.TOP, 0);
        
document.Close();

Everything is fine - the page numbers appears in the bottom right section of the document correctly without any inversion.
Please advise how can it be fixed.

The merged documents could have rotated pages.
I only see the addition of numbers, how is the text ending up on the pages?

Yes, page rotation may be part of the issue. But the numbers are not simply rotated, they are mirrored. Thus, I think that here also some transformation matrix effect is bleeding through. The op should try enforcing that the existing page content is enclosed in save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelopes before they add the numbers. Nonetheless, for general use also page rotation and page crop boxes need to be taken into account.
